# c++ dynamic arrays and pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, corrupt

Ok so what I'm trying to do is create an array of pointers that point to vectors that change in size. Also the array of pointers is nestled inside a class that's inside a vector. For some reason I seem to be having problems with memory becoming corrupt. Also if I use vectors I run into the problems with the stack overflowing caused by stuff resizing and calling constructors. Here is an essential layout of what I'm gunning for.

[image: Diagram]

Maybe a little sloppy. But I end up with the problem of memory being currupted in the babyclasses pointers, basically I want to access "linked" babyclasses via the babyclasses vector of babyclasses it's connected to. 
Any clever ideas here?

And before anyone tells me this is a silly way to do things, isn't this type of functionality the basis of OO Programming?

```
class Baby
{
public:
    deque<shared_ptr<Baby>> vInputs;
    int X;
    int Y;
    int Z;
    Baby()
    {
        numInputs = 0;
        isNull = false;
        wasTickled = false;
        X,Y,Z = 0;

    }
    void addInput(shared_ptr<Baby> baby)
    {
        if(numInputs == 0)
            vInputs = deque<shared_ptr<Baby>>(0);
        vInputs.push_back(baby);
        numInputs++;
    }
    void setXYZ(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }
    void Tickle()
    {
        if(!wasTickled)
            wasTickled = true;
        else
            return;
        for(int i=0;i<numInputs;i++)
        {
            vInputs[i]->Tickle();
        }
    }
    void setNull(bool isnull)
    {
        isNull = isnull;
    }
private:
    int numInputs;
    bool isNull;
    bool wasTickled;
};
class BabyLayer
{
public:
    int Width;
    int Height;
    BabyLayer()
    {
        Width = 0;
        Height = 0;
    }
    BabyLayer(int width, int height)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
        vecBabies = std::deque<deque<Baby>>(0);
        for(int i=0;i<height;i++)
        {
            deque<Baby> row = deque<Baby>(0);
            for(int i=0;i<width;i++)
            {
                row.push_back(Baby());
            };
            vecBabies.push_back(row);
        }
        MakeConnections();
    }

    Baby * getBaby(int x, int y)
    {
        Baby n = Baby();
        n.setNull(true);
        if(x >= Width || x <0)
            return &n;
        if(y >= Height || y < 0)
            return &n;
        n.setNull(false);
        return &vecBabies[y][x];
    }
    ~BabyLayer(void)
    {

    }
private:
    std::deque<deque<Baby>> vecBabies;
    void MakeConnections()
    {
        for(int y=0;y<Height;y++)
        {
            for(int x=0;x<Width;x++)
            {
                //Top Right
                if(y > 0 && x < Width-1)
                    vecBabies[y][x].addInput(shared_ptr<Baby>(&vecBabies[y-1][x+1]));
                //Middle Right
                if(x < Width -1)
                    vecBabies[y][x].addInput(shared_ptr<Baby>(&vecBabies[y][x+1]));
                //Bottom Right
                if(x < Width -1 && y < Height-1)
                    vecBabies[y][x].addInput(shared_ptr<Baby>(&vecBabies[y+1][x+1]));
                //Bottom Middle
                if(y < Height-1)
                    vecBabies[y][x].addInput(shared_ptr<Baby>(&vecBabies[y+1][x]));
            }
        }
    }
};
class BabyCube
{
public:
    int X;
    int Y;
    int Z;
    BabyCube(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
        Layers = deque<BabyLayer>();
        for(int i=0;i<z;i++)
        {
            BabyLayer lay = BabyLayer(x,y);
            Layers.push_back(lay);
        }
        NullBaby = Baby();
        NullBaby.setNull(true);
        MakeConnections();
    }
    void MakeConnections()
    {
        int l = Layers.size();
        if(l == 0 || l == 1)
            return;
        for(int layer=0;layer<l;layer++)
        {
            BabyLayer * lay = &Layers[layer];
            if(layer< l-1)
            {
                for(int y=0;y<lay->Height;y++)
                {
                    for(int x=0;x<lay->Width;x++)
                    {
                        //Top Left
                        if(x > 0 && y > 0)
                            Layers[layer].getBaby(x,y)->addInput(shared_ptr<Baby>(Layers[layer+1].getBaby(x-1,y-1)));
                        //Top Middle
                        if(y > 0)
                            Layers[layer].getBaby(x,y)->addInput(shared_ptr<Baby>(Layers[layer+1].getBaby(x,y-1)));
                        //Top Right
                        if(y > 0 && x+1 < lay->Width-1)
                            Layers[layer].getBaby(x,y)->addInput(shared_ptr<Baby>(Layers[layer+1].getBaby(x+1,y-1)));
                        //Middle Right
                        if(x+1 < lay->Width -1)
                            Layers[layer].getBaby(x,y)->addInput(shared_ptr<Baby>(Layers[layer+1].getBaby(x+1,y)));
                        //Bottom Right
                        if(x+1 < lay->Width -1 && y+1 < lay->Height-1)
                            Layers[layer].getBaby(x,y)->addInput(shared_ptr<Baby>(Layers[layer+1].getBaby(x+1,y+1)));
                        //Bottom Middle
                        if(y+1 < lay->Height-1)
                            Layers[layer].getBaby(x,y)->addInput(shared_ptr<Baby>(Layers[layer+1].getBaby(x,y+1)));
                        //Bottom Left
                        if(x > 0 && y+1 < lay->Height-1)
                            Layers[layer].getBaby(x,y)->addInput(shared_ptr<Baby>(Layers[layer+1].getBaby(x-1,y+1)));
                        //Middle Left
                        if(x > 0)
                            Layers[layer].getBaby(x,y)->addInput(shared_ptr<Baby>(Layers[layer+1].getBaby(x-1,y)));
                        //Middle Middle
                        Layers[layer].getBaby(x,y)->addInput(shared_ptr<Baby>(Layers[layer+1].getBaby(x,y)));
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
    Baby * getBaby(int x, int y, int z)
    {

        if(z >= Layers.size() || z < 0)
            return &NullBaby;
        if(y >= Layers[z].Height || y < 0)
            return &NullBaby;
        if(x >= Layers[z].Width || x < 0)
            return &NullBaby;

        return Layers[z].getBaby(x,y);
    }
    void Update()
    {

    }
    ~BabyCube(void)
    {

    }
private:
    deque<BabyLayer> Layers;
    Baby NullBaby;
};
```

Comment: Is this a fixed size array of pointers in your class? How are you determining the size of the array and initializing the array? Post some code please.

Comment: I'm assuming that my corruption comes from the actual locations of my data changing, but isn't there some way to avoid that? I just feel like I'm missing something simple here.

Comment: No they are vectors. I initialize the arrays like this. vector<class*>(), then do a push back, and I don't do it on the class default constructor(since it's all nested in a away) I initialize the vector only if the class add's a pointer, again to minimize the posibility of a stack overflow due to the vector class initializing my stuff.

Comment: "Ok so what I'm trying to do is create an array of pointers that point to vectors that change in size" "isn't this type of functionality the basis of OO Programming" No.

Comment: What is a "babyclass"? And can you tell us what you're _actually_ trying to do, rather than (or aswell as) the low-level details of how you tried to do it?

Comment: `vector<class*>()` will give you an empty vector. You need to pass it a size. The vector cannot initialize an element that is just a pointer. If you have a vector of pointers, either you're storing the address of an already initialized class, or you're building a new class on the heap with the `new` operator and storing the return address.

Comment: Having examined your diagram for a few minutes, I have to say that it makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @kelton52: Rather than the diagram, you really need to post the code. We're not sure exactly what you mean here because it sounds like you don't know exactly what you mean. Post the code and we'll be able to tell you whether it makes sense or not. Note however that naked pointers inside STL containers are usually asking for pain. Perhaps storing something like `std::shared_ptr`s instead, or `std::unique_ptr`s, or using something like `boost::ptr_container::ptr_vector` instead.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal I think it is. Here is an example http://www.carlopescio.com/2011/04/your-coding-conventions-are-hurting-you.html

Comment: @Billy ONeal I've tried shared_ptr's and ptr_containers, but they don't seem to like to live inside other stl containers.

Comment: @kelton52: They have no such restrictions. If you're having problems there, you're simply using them incorrectly. Post the code, please. There's little we can say about your code if we cannot see it.

Comment: @kelton you are using shared_ptr incorrectly then. Please post your code. The diagram is nice but not terribly helpful to diagnose your problem.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: It can initialise a pointer just fine. It'll be initialised to `0`.

Comment: @kelton52: I do not consider that random blog to be authoritative. Using containers in the most indirect and convoluted fashion possible is most certainly _not_ "the basis of OO programming", no matter what it says.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: (And classes do not have addresses.)

Comment: @Tomalak, are you sure vector<myclass *> will intialize a elements to 0? Obviously I meant object not class, duh me.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: Container elements are default- [if not copy-] constructed, yes. (Of course, nothing will happen to any pointee that does or does not exist; _the element is the pointer_.)

Comment: @Tomalak, I know the element is the pointer, but if I construct a non-empty vector of pointers, are the pointers guarenteed to be initialized to 0? I don't see that defined anywhere.

Comment: @Tomalak, unless I give it an explicit initial value, like `vector<int *> v(10, 0);`. Otherwise I think it's undefined.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: The constructor you're using is `explicit vector(size_type n, const T& value = T(), const Allocator& = Allocator());`. The element construction is in the default value for the second argument. [2003/23.2.4.1]

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal It wasn't just some blog post, it was refering to papers written by the people developing these things. Isn't object orientated, orientated twords objects, and their ability to interact instead of being just structures. That's why its OO, the classes are alive.

Comment: @Tomalak, that's my point. Now if I say `vector<int *> v(10);` I maintain that `v[0]` is now undefined. Just like after `int * vv[10];`, `vv[0]` is undefined. Am I incorrect?

Comment: no with vector it will still be defined, the size just gets set to 0.

Comment: @kelton52, does this code compile completely without errors? Can you narrow down after what method you're getting corruption?

Comment: yeah the code compiles, the whole thing initializes great, it's just when i MakeConnections, to add the pointers, they are corrupt.

Comment: in fact it seems as though all my pointers are pointing at the same thing, well memory space anyways.

Comment: Does the address happen to be 0xCCCCCCCC or something like that? I have a feeling that these pointers are not initialized correctly.

Comment: no, its shared_ptr {X=0xfeeefeee Y=0xfeeefeee Z=0xfeeefeee ...} [0x00000001 strong ref] [default] std::tr1::shared_ptr<Baby>

Comment: well I check the address on one of them, it was 002cfbf4, doesn't seem wrong to me? I'm sure all of them have the same address though

Comment: Your design and data structures are rather opaque. That said, I don't see anything obviously incorrect. Can you set some ASSERTs? If all the pointers are pointing the same address, set a breakpoint on the pointer assignment statement to see if the correct address is actually stored.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: It's totally a real question, there is code, and an obvious problem. The memory is being corrupted somehow. Look ^^^^^^^^^^, Code.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: I agree it's a real question, perhaps not very articulate, but a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of morbid curiosity, I revisited this question to see if anyone had deciphered it.

The only obvious issue I see with the source code is in BabyLayer::GetBaby():

```
    Baby n = Baby();
    n.setNull(true);
    if(x >= Width || x <0)
        return &n;             // Bad.
    if(y >= Height || y < 0)
        return &n;             // Bad.
```

You're declaring a new Baby instance on the stack, then returning a pointer to it.  The Baby instance named 'n' gets destructed when GetBaby() returns, and the returned pointer is now invalid.

I don't know what compiler you're using, but Visual Studio 2010 emits, "warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary" on these lines.  Note that your code sample is incomplete and doesn't actually do anything, I had to declare a BabyCube instance to receive this warning.

Since I can't decipher what your code is supposed to do, and can make no sense of its operation, I can't explain why the memory access exceptions are thrown.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why I did that. Completely missed it.

Comment: By the way, if you're curious(or maybe frightened), this was an attempt at a neural network. I got it working awhile ago after giving my head a few days to clear(always seems to help when ur stuck, you can make the stupidest mistakes^^^). Anyways I'm giving you the check cause you found a problem.